# Redux saga action undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

obviously can post more code but cant work out why my action is returning me undefined here? where should I be passing the data in to this action?

```
function* fetchInitialData(action) {
  console.log(action, 'acshun'); //IS UNDEFINED HERE
  try {
    const dataFromFirebase = yield call(pullFromFirebase, action.data)
    yield put({ type: "DATA_FETCHED_SUCCESSFULLY", data: dataFromFirebase})
  }
}

function* mySaga() {
  yield takeLatest("SYNC_FIREBASE_TO_STORE", fetchInitialData)
}
```

my action:

```
export const syncFirebaseToStore = (data) => ({
  type: 'SYNC_FIREBASE_TO_STORE',
  data: data
})
```

Comment: From where are you calling fetchInitialData

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri from mySaga..

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Also interested in a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Action is always added as last argument to the saga argument defined by `take`,`takeEvery` an `takeLatest`. This code snippet looks correct. So you would need to share more code, on first sight I think the generator is called outside of the saga middleware, or you're not using the `takeLatest` from the redux-saga library.